# Vue material - single selection for md-table using slots

Tags: vue.js, slots, vue-material

In Vue Material Table component there is an explanation for single selection, which in codepen doesn't work https://vuematerial.io/components/table (SCROLL TO SINGLE SELECTION). I want working example of this making sure that the list to be rendered is from API.

Comment: What about it doesn't work?

Comment: Selected item data should be displayed in below paragraph element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example on [Vue Material - Table / Selection / Single](https://vuematerial.io/components/table) requires `vue-material@1.0.0-beta-8` to run.

The pen that opens is using `https://unpkg.com/vue-material@beta` as dependency (See at **Pen Settings** -> JavaScript tab).

Currently `https://unpkg.com/vue-material@beta` resolves to `https://unpkg.com/vue-material@1.0.0-beta-7/dist/vue-material.min.js`. Shouldn't take long until it starts to point to `beta-8`.

#### Solution:

Nevertheless, until it updates the version, you should add the dependency `https://unpkg.com/vue-material@1.0.0-beta-8/dist/vue-material.min.js` yourself:

- Button **Settings**
- **JavaScript** tab
- Third URL down below: where it is `https://unpkg.com/vue-material@beta` make it `https://unpkg.com/vue-material@1.0.0-beta-8/dist/vue-material.min.js`
- Profit.

Check an **updated pen** (where I changed it): https://codepen.io/acdcjunior/pen/yKBvgL

Comment: Unfortunately no, because that single selection and the associated events were added in version 1.